# A fast thread-safe way to identify method calls originating from the superclass

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, inheritance

Let's consider a third-party class `A` with the following characteristics:

1. Most of its implementation is private and quite complex, so it can be extended but *not* reasonably modified.
2. `A` has a *very* expensive constructor that should *never* be called unnecessarily - in my case it builds a *huge* lookup table of data for later use.

   This means that creating a [decorator class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) as a drop-in replacement for `A` is out of the question, since any decorator would have to inherit from `A` and call its constructor.
3. `A` is used by third-party code, so a [proxy class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) cannot be used in its place - other code expects instances of `A` and that is what it should get.
4. `A` provides a bunch of *very* expensive reporting methods that *frabble* a lot of *wrabbles* to produce a bunch of reports.

   These methods do not produce any locally-used result - they could *theoretically* be asynchronous, but unfortunately they are not.
5. The methods of `A` call each other - a lot.
6. The `A` implementation is opaque and in constant flux - hacks like using reflection post-instantiation to e.g. slim things down are out of the question.
7. `A` is not thread-safe - not really...

I reached a point where `A` became a bottleneck in a project of mine, so I created a child class `B` hoping to push the actual *frabbling* of *wrabbles* to a separate thread. I overrode all public methods of `A` to just submit `Runnable` objects to a single-thread executor service. Each `Runnable` then executes the appropriate `super` method from the worker thread.

Unfortunately, `A` calls its own public methods *a lot*. Normally that would not be a problem, but in my case the superclass is calling methods from `B`. That *is* a major issue, because the `B` methods *defer* the actual execution and submit new tasks to the executor service, leading to both performance and correctness issues.

My solution was to check the result of [`Thread.currentThread()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#currentThread%28%29) in all methods from `B` so that calls coming from the worker thread will be delegated directly to the `super` method rather than being submitted as a new task.

So now I am at the point where it's `Thread.currentThread()` that has become a performance issue, probably due to its being a native method that is called way too often.

- Is there a faster way to check for method calls that originate from the superclass and/or the worker thread in a thread-safe manner?
- Is there an alternative design that would allow me to push `A`'s *frabbling* of *wrabbles* to another thread? It seems to me that due to `A` being third-party code I am mostly trapped...

Comment: What is a "locally-used result" (local to what?) and what does this have to do with asynchronous (did you mean thread-safe?)

Comment: @meriton: I mean that the reporting method calls are fire-and-forget. I do not have to *wait* for them to finish...

Comment: `Thread.currentThread()` is very fast, how would it be a problem? Especially it is called once before the supposedly very expensive operation, it shouldn't be noticeable.

Comment: @irreputable: the problem is that the very expensive operation calls the other public methods in `A` several thousand times. Since those methods are also used by other classes I cannot delegate directly to `super` - I have to check if the call should be submitted to the worker thread.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a faster way to check for method calls that originate from
>   the superclass and/or the worker thread in a thread-safe manner?

You could replace `Thread.currentThread` with a [ThreadLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html). 
Just set e.g. a `Boolean` to `ThreadLocal` and if set (check it as you enter the method), don't spawn a new thread but instead execute on same thread.

**Update**
Use a hashmap to keep a trail of the method calls.Once you go into a method check if it exists in the hashmap (the method's name as key).
If it does not exist then put in the the hashmap and call the method using a background thread.
If it exists then you must be already in a background thread. So do the call in the same thread

Comment: As `ThreadLocal.get()` invokes `Thread.currentThread()`, why would this improve performance as opposed to directly comparing the currentThread?

Comment: @meriton:Does it?I thought it is a hashmap based on thread ids

Comment: @Cratylus: and how would I get the thread name without calling `Thread.currentThread()`?

Comment: @thkala:When you create a thread the first time you call a method of `A` give it a name.Store that name in the hashtable.You don't need to get the name of the current thread.All you need is to check the hashtable to see if a thread has been created with a predefined name.You could use the method name

Comment: @Cratylus: I am sorry, but I cannot understand what you are proposing. If I use the method name wouldn't that just check if the same method has been called higher in the call tree?

Comment: @thkala:Yes I wasn't clear I am sorry.I updated answer.Just keep a trail of the method calls.

Answer (score 0):

As `A` is not thread-safe, invoking it with different threads is not ... safe.

Ideas:

- You could be pooling instances of `A`, i.e. whenever a thread needs an A, it obtains one from the pool (or creates one if the pool is empty), uses it, and then puts it back into the pool. That way, you will have as many instances of A as are needed at the same time.
- You could patch `A` to cache the "huge lookup table" across instances (of course, that requires it to be thread-safe, but if the table is only read after construction, that is trivially the case), and use a new instance of `A` in every thread.

Comment: 1. I do not need to invoke `A` from multiple threads - I just need do push its processing off the main thread and to a separate one, essentially making the calls asynchronous.

Comment: 2. I only have *one* instance of `A` - I don't want to even *think* what it would take to have a whole pool of the little *expletive-removed* around...

Comment: 3. Patching `A` requires (a) access to the source code and (b) the will to tangle with that mess. I have neither. I guess I will just have to annoy the people that wrote it hoping for some sort of improvement... or look for a replacement...

Comment: Patching does not require the source code as you can disassemble the class file (granted, if it is obfuscated, the resulting code will be hard to patch ...)

Comment: it don't think that it's obfuscated, but I would have to both get a proper decompiled source - and from my experience even Java decompilers are not that good in producing correct code - and *maintain* the damn thing. Somehow that does not sound much fun :-)

Comment: Quite honestly it's starting to look like I need to plan for replacing the little *-censored-*. I was hoping for some sort of magic trick to get around a little longer, but alas...

Comment: How about disclosing the identity of A? Is it a public library that other non suspecting devs can fall on?

Comment: @Vitaliy: thankfully it is not public and I'd rather not point any fingers. But there are other classes with the some of the same issues. Java `PrintStream` comes to mind...

Answer (score 0):

If your runtime environment allows use of custom class loaders, you should be able replace the third party class A with a custom delegate class that uses reflection to invoke the original class A.

Here's an example of delegate Class A:

```
package fi.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class ClassA {
    private static final Class<?> clazz;
    private static final Method doSomething;
    private Object instance;

    static {
        ClassLoader classLoader = new ClassLoader(ClassA.class.getClassLoader()) {
            @Override
            public synchronized Class<?> loadClass(String name)
                    throws ClassNotFoundException {
                if (!name.equals(ClassA.class.getName())) {
                    return super.loadClass(name);
                }
                Class<?> clazz = findLoadedClass(name);
                if (clazz == null) {
                    // The original class A is stored as ClassA.class.orig
                    InputStream inputStream = getParent().getResourceAsStream(
                            "fi/test/ClassA.class.orig");
                    try {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[100000];
                        int length = inputStream.read(buffer);
                        clazz = defineClass(name, buffer, 0, length);
                    } catch (IOException exception) {
                        throw new ClassNotFoundException("", exception);
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            inputStream.close();
                        } catch (IOException exception) {
                        }
                    }
                }
                return clazz;
            }
        };
        try {
            // Class A
            clazz = classLoader.loadClass(ClassA.class.getName());
            // Do something
            doSomething = clazz.getMethod("doSomething", new Class<?>[0]);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            throw new Error(exception);
        }
    }

    public ClassA() {
        try {
            instance = clazz.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }

    }

    public void doSomething() {
        try {
            doSomething.invoke(instance, new Object[0]);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the original Class A:

```
package fi.test;

public class ClassA {
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("This is magic!");
    }
}
```

And this is the class that I used to test the delegate:

```
package fi.test;

public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassA instance = new ClassA();
        instance.doSomething();
    }
}
```